# Laravel Queue on Repository

Tags: php, laravel

I am using laravel as api for angular js app and i have a newsletter api call and the success of that call takes more time so i thought to use queue system , created a queue job and I can access the queue from controller , but i can not access from repository

```
namespace App\Jobs;

use App\Jobs\Job;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Bus\SelfHandling;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;

class SendStudentRequirement extends Job implements SelfHandling,ShouldQueue
{
   use InteractsWithQueue, SerializesModels;
   protected $data;

   public function __construct($data)
   {
      $this->data = $data;
   }

   public function handle()
   {
    file_put_contents('test.txt', $this->data);
   }
}
```

When i call `$this->dispatch(new SendStudentRequirement('data test'));` from controller its working fine , but from repository its throwing error as undefined SendStudentRequirement.

Comment: Please check https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/mail

Comment: please read the question now @AddWebSolutionPvtLtd

Comment: (1) did you import "App\Jobs\SendStudentRequirement" in the repo? (2)$this->dispatch is valid in the repo??

Comment: yes i imported use App\Jobs\SendStudentRequirement;
        use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\DispatchesJobs;  but still throws error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use queues: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/queues

I dont know which provider you use, but there some built in email providers and even if you have an other one that is not a problem.

Simply implement a message queue and handler that will send your emails, so the response for the client should be quick

Comment: I am using normal php mail as the client dont want those paid things

Comment: if you have a server that supports it, then great, even though those paid plans has quite a nice quantity for free.

Comment: i am using normal php mail() function is it possible to make this into a queue ?

Comment: yes it is not a problem, the mail provider is not relevant to the queue.

Comment: is queue can be implimented from repository ?

Comment: sorry what does that mean? :/

Comment: Forget about the email things , i created a queue job and from controller its working but from repository its not working

Comment: please post your code in the post, so I could answer properly